# google ical issue in calculating recurring events dates

Tags: icalendar, rfc2445, rfc5545

The issue got for the following event.

```
BEGIN:VEVENT
UID:483b7d72-7412-4aca-92f1-b7bf427a9c5a
RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=3;INTERVAL=1;BYDAY=MO,TU,WE,TH,FR
SUMMARY:tes
DTSTART;TZID="Asia/Tokyo":20131215T000000
DTEND;TZID="Asia/Tokyo":20131215T003000
STATUS:CONFIRMED
CLASS:PUBLIC
X-MICROSOFT-CDO-INTENDEDSTATUS:BUSY
TRANSP:OPAQUE
X-MICROSOFT-DISALLOW-COUNTER:TRUE
DTSTAMP:20130606T064916Z
SEQUENCE:2
END:VEVENT
```

For this event , google library (rfc2445-4Mar2011.jar) returns 4 repeating days.

output dates are 20131215T000000, 20131216T000000 , 20131217T000000, 20131218T000000

But i set  rrule count as 3 for this event. even then i got 4 repeating days.

please help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

this is indeed a bug in the library

rfc2445 §3.1.10

> The COUNT rule part defines the number of occurrences at which to range-bound the recurrence. The "DTSTART" property value, if specified, counts as the first occurrence.

even the rfc5545 which superseds it states §3.3.10

> The COUNT rule part defines the number of occurrences at which to range-bound the recurrence.  The "DTSTART" property value always counts as the first occurrence.

from which it is clear that the list of recurences would be:

20131215T000000, 20131216T000000 , 20131217T000000

Answer (score 0):

Can only confirm that this is a bug in your library. For what it is worth, ical4j correctly expands this RRULE.

Answer (score 0):

Your DTSTART does not fit your RRULE: DTSTART is a Sunday but your RRULE limits dates to Monday->Friday.  Given this I suspect that different codebases will interpret this in different ways.  You should strongly consider altering your event so that it is more standard.